# Getting "This class does not support SAAJ 1.1" when calling SoapMessage.getSOAPBody().hasFault()

Tags: java, web-services, soap-client

when i am calling a webservice and trying to check if the response message has fault object by calling response.getSOAPBody().hasFault()

i am getting "This class does not support SAAJ 1.1" error
 Any clue what could be the reason

Answer (score 0):

I hit this while using Weblogic 10.3.6.

Apparently the following system property will clear it up:

```
./javacloud set-system-property -user userName -identitydomain identityDomain -serviceinstance serviceInstance -name javax.xml.soap.MessageFactory -value weblogic.xml.saaj.MessageFactoryImpl
```

You can find more [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/javase-cloud/csjsu/saaj-1.1-is-not-supported.html)